# Is this the right way to shutdown prism application without default exit button?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

The window of app do not have boarder, so there is no exit button on the right conner?How can I close it in right way?

This is my way, fisrt bind a command to custom exit button.

```
<Button Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="327,198,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"/>
```

Than throw a exception in a ViewModel when button clicked.

```
class ViewModel:NotificationObject
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.ExitCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(this.ExecuteExitCommand));
    }

    public DelegateCommand ExitCommand { get; set; }

    public void ExecuteExitCommand()
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("shutdown");
    }
}
```

Catch the exception in Application class

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomainUnhandledException;
        try
        {
            bootstrapper.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void AppDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
    }

    private static void HandleException(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex == null)
            return;
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just maybe use `Application.Current.Shutdown()` ??

```
public void ExecuteExitCommand()
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Using an Exception as a communication mechanism just seems weird.

If you do not want to invoke ShutDown() in the VM for whatever reason, use a `Messenger`(in Prism that's `EventAggregator`) to send a custom message which you can subscribe from the Application Class or the MainWindow's code-behind and invoke the same `Application.Current.Shutdown()`

Comment: An exception as a communication mechanism seems weird, until you have an unhandled one.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to do:

```
private DelegateCommand terminateApplication;
public ICommand TerminateApplication => terminateApplication ??= new 
DelegateCommand(PerformTerminateApplication);

private void PerformTerminateApplication()
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```